# Cannot find module "@angular/common/http"

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I have upgraded my npm to the latest version. The npm folder in my Visual Studio Application reads v6.0.3 while my package.json file also corresponds to this version 6.0.3.

But any time I run my application I get the error cannot find module on the browser

[image: See Picture of error]

I believe HttpClient is used in versions above 3x but obviously have a higher version installed.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { QuizListComponent } from './components/quiz/quiz-list.component';



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        QuizListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

pakage.json

```
{
  "name": "ExamBuddy",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.7",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "css": "2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "2.0.2",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.8.3",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }
}
```

Comment: you may be try to import httpCilent from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: There was never an version `3` of angular, anyways you can try after running this command `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean -f`

Comment: i meant the versions in the Package.json file .........

Answer (score 5):

You need to have latest version of `angular http`:

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

Import `HttpClient` in your service component (if required):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` //already there in your code:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions to this problem and they are:

1. If your project has more than one module then you have to import `HttpClientModule` from `'@angular/common/http'` in every module you have.
2. Add HttpClient inside providers from modules your project has, see the example:

   ```
   providers:[
      UserService, 
      HttpClient]
   ```

It is preferred to import HttpClientModule into each module.

3. Remove the node_modules folder and clean the npm cache. Then install all dependencies typing `npm i. Execute de code below:

> `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean -f && npm i`

Answer (score 0):

You may be try to **import HttpMoudle from '@angular/common/http'** so in any case 
Http and HttpModule the can import from '@angular/http', but 
HttpClient and HttpClientModule the are importe from '@angular/common/http'.

so if use`HttpClient` in your component/service and must you import `HttpClientModule` in your `@NgModule`

example :

```
// app.module.ts:

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

Comment: i have added the following                                                                 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; to the app.module and i have also included it under the imports. but i still have the same problem.

Comment: have you try run npm install ??

Comment: Yes i have. npm is installed fine

Comment: Can you share with us app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
npm i @angular
```